# async requests are handled by one python flask process through IIS

Tags: python, iis, flask, wsgi

I published Flask application through IIS, When I send 10 concurrent requests to the flask application, they are handled one by one.

so if the request processing time is 2 seconds, the 10th request finishes after 20 seconds.

How can I configure the IIS and flask to distribute the requests on multiple processes

Thanks

Comment: When researching this, all signs point to "give up and use apache". I would really like to know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: @Zak in the fastcgi settings, I set max instances to 8, this is working for me, but I think apache over linux may be a better option